# Distribution of $Z=\operatorname{max}(X,Y)-X$ when $X\perp Y\sim \operatorname{Geo}(p)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I did $F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{max}(X,Y)-X\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(0\leq z,X>Y)+\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z+x,X<Y)$. Thus:

1. $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z+x,X<Y)=\mathbb{P}(x<Y<z+x)=\sum_{s=x}^{z+x}\mathbb{P}(Y=s)=\sum_{s=x}^{z+x}p(1-p)^{s-1}=p\sum_{s=x}^{z+x}(1-p)^{s-1}$, so $j=s-x\Rightarrow s=j+x\Rightarrow \sum_{s=x}^{z+x}=\sum_{j=0}^{z}\rightarrow p\sum_{j=0}^{z}(1-p)^{j+x-1}=p\cdot \frac{(1-p)^0-(1-p)^z}{1-(1-p)}=\frac{p-pq^z}{1-q}$ but the result is $\frac{pq^z}{1+q}$: why? Initially I thought was correct because working around some computations I have $\frac{p-pq^z}{1-q}=1-q^z$, that is the CDF of a geometric variable, but it is not.
2. How do I have to calculate $\mathbb{P}(0\leq z)$?

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z+x,X<Y)$ should be $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z+X,X<Y)$ THere is no constant $x$ here.

Comment: Regarding the second question: $\mathbb{P}(0\leq z) = \mathbb{1}_{z\ge 0}$

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for your answers. For the first question, why is it wrong $\mathbb{P}(Y-X\leq z,X<Y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z+x,X<Y)$?

Comment: Because in the left side you have $X$,  a random variable, and in the right side you rewrite it as if it were a constant $x$. What is $x$?

Comment: @leonbloy Sure, $x$ in the right side is a constant, but in this way I'm expliciting $Y$. Or not?

Comment: @leonbloy Ok, so how should I calculate that probability?

Comment: You sum over all possible values for $X$.

Comment: Regarding question $2$, it is impossible for $z < 0$, since $\max(x, y) \ge x$.

Answer (score 1):

$X\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)\implies\mathsf P(X{=}x)=p(1-p)^x \,\mathbf 1_{x\in\Bbb N}$

$\quad\begin{align}F_{\small Z}(z) & =\mathsf P(\max(X,Y)-X\leqslant z)
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(\max(0,Y-X)\leqslant z)
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(0\leqslant z, Y<X)+\mathsf P(Y\leqslant X+z, X\leqslant Y)
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(Y<X)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}+\mathsf P(X\leqslant Y\leqslant X+z)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(Y\leqslant X+z)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}
\\[0ex]&= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}\,\sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=0}^{x+z} p^2(1-p)^{x+y}
\\[0ex]&~~\vdots
\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks, I understand all that, but why the solution is divided in two parts? And I quote: $p_0=\frac{1}{1+q};   p_k=\frac{pq^z}{1+q}$? In addition, in the denominator I always have $1-q$ and not $1+q$...